# Return HTTP response in the function called by view

Tags: python, django

In view, I accepts json keys and values in request.body. I plan to check for the existence of the json keys required (typo maybe) in another function

```
def checkJsonKey(form, *args):
    for key in enumerate(args):
        if key not in form:
            return HttpResponse(status = 400) #<--
```

Instead of doing checking on the returned value, can this function directly return response and terminate this view function?

In my view function,

```
form = json.loads(request.body)


checkJsonKey(form,"user_preference","model_id", "filename")
```

Comment: Have you tried json.loads() ??

Comment: form = json.loads(request.body)

checkJsonKey(form, "user_preference","model_id", "filename")

they are in my view

Comment: json.loads(request.body) would return you an the json object converted in python's dict modue. You can directly access the keys from it I suppose. If you wish to check that if the key `user_preference` is present, you can directly call it from `form['user_preference']`

Comment: then I need to use try & except to determine if the key is there... which is not that nice for me to do checking in the main view =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how i would handle this, using an exception and then catching it, rather than returning the response, this allows you to return a number of error conditions from your function and handle them in a try/except catcher.

```
def checkJsonKey(form, *args):
    if type(form) not dict:
        raise ValueError("Not dict")
    # assuming you actually want to deal with a list of the args, and not a turple pairs from enumerate
    for key in list(args):
        # assuming that form is a dict
        if key not in form.keys():
            raise ValueError("Key not found")
    return True
```

this would be called as

```
form = json.loads(request.body)

try:
    checkJsonKey(form,"user_preference","model_id", "filename")
except ValueError as e:
    return HttpResponseBadRequest("%s" % e)
# rest of the code
```

if you wanted to get really fancy, you could define your own error class and specifically catch for that

Comment: I ended up using try and except as well. But since I will be assigning values in json into python variable, I included all the value assigning operations into the try, and catch the Key Error and return 400 in the Except ! =)

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value returned from `checkJsonKey` is None, if it is not, then it must have returned your Response and you can return that from the view function.

```
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = json.loads(request.body)
    response = checkJsonKey(form, *args)
    if response is not None:
        return response
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't make much difference, but if you want another method, json.loads() returns a dictionary from the json string passed to it, of which existence of keys can easily be checked by calling the `form[key]` syntax. You can further check the docs of the json API [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html).

Try this:

```
def checkJsonKey(form, *args):
    for key in enumerate(args):
        if form[key] != None:
            return False
        return True

def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = json.loads(request.body)
    response = checkJsonKey(form, *args)
    if response:
        return HttpResponse(status = 200)
    else:
        return HttpResponse(status = 400)
```